# Why aren't these different button types lining up?

Tags: html, css, button, alignment

I have a  and an  on my page.  However, I cannot seem to get these buttons to line up.

*html*

```
<div class="doubleButtonContainer">
    <button class="moreAnswersButton" name="more_answers" onclick="showAllAnswers()">More answer fields...</button>
    <input type="submit" class="button" name="submit" value="Finish" />
</div>
```

*css*

```
.moreAnswersButton, .button
{
    height: 50px;
    width: 125px;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 0;
}

.doubleButtonContainer
{
    height: 70px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 325px;
}
```

[JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/0vrrehyz/)

Comment: `verrical-align: top;` is what you want there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add 'vertical-align' property to your to your buttons.

```
.moreAnswersButton, .button
    {
        height: 50px;
        width: 125px;
        text-align: center;
        border-radius: 5px;
        padding: 0;
        vertical-align: bottom;
    }
```

(the value can be bottom, middle or top. it's your preference)